# Dynamically generated buttons don't occupy even space in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` in which I want Buttons to be generated dynamically. I have specified the number of rows & columns of the `GridLayout` in XML. I want the generated buttons to occupy even amount of space in the `GridLayout`.

That is to say, if I have three columns, all three buttons should occupy same space. Now I have seen a few examples here on StackOverflow that suggest making use of `android:layout_width`, but none of them contain examples of dynamically generated Views & I don't know if and how `layout_width` can be added to a `View` component like `Button`.

I want my `GridLayout` to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL0I2.png), but all I'm getting is this

[image: this]

Following is the XML that contains `GridLayout`

```
<GridLayout
                            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:columnCount="2"
                            android:rowCount="2"
                            android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical">
                        </GridLayout>
```

Following is the dynamic generation of `Buttons`

```
netbankingGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

        //First Cell on the Grid
        {
            Button button1 = new Button(this);
            button1.setText("Button1");
            Drawable image = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ar_hdfc);
            image.setBounds(0,0,70,70);
            button1.setCompoundDrawables(null,image,null, null);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_bg1);
            netbankingGrid.addView(button1);
        }

        //Second Cell on the Grid
        {

            Button button2 = new Button(this);
            button2.setText("Button2");
            Drawable image = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ar_hdfc);
            image.setBounds(0,0,70,70);
            button2.setCompoundDrawables(null,image,null, null);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_bg2);
            netbankingGrid.addView(button2);
        }

        //Third Cell on the Grid
        {

            Button button3 = new Button(this);
            button3.setText("Button3");
            Drawable image = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ar_hdfc);
            image.setBounds(0,0,70,70);
            button3.setCompoundDrawables(null,image,null, null);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_bg3);
            netbankingGrid.addView(button3);
        }

        //Fourth Cell on the Grid
        {

            Button button4 = new Button(this);
            button4.setText("Button4");
            Drawable image = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ar_hdfc);
            image.setBounds(0,0,70,70);
            button4.setCompoundDrawables(null,image,null, null);
            button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_bg4);
            netbankingGrid.addView(button4);
        }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try `netbankingGrid.addView(position, button);` adding view with position.

Comment: There's nothing called `position` in the `addVIew`. There is, however, something called `index` & when I try that, it throws an error

Comment: Use Linear Layout with weight, it might be helpful

Comment: Specification requires use of `GridLayout`. Isn't there any workaround for this?

Comment: Set button width as match_parent

Comment: width: `match_parent`

Comment: Try setting each buttons width and height Match_Parent. `button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

Comment: Nope. Each button is occupying the whole space due to which Button1 & Button 3 are displayed (covering the width of the entire GridLayout), but the other two are not displayed